# Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'FormStyleConfiguration' that does not accept a closure

Tags: swiftui

im trying to display a list of categries from database in combo box , i write this form of code but it display same error : **my code** `   @StateObject var viewModel: MyShopViewModel = MyShopViewModel()

```
@ObservedObject var catVm: CategoryViewModel

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            
            Form {
               Section(header: Text("Product Information")) {
                   TextField("Product Name", text: .constant(""))
                   TextField("Product Description", text: .constant(""))
                   TextField("Product Price", text: .constant(""))
               }
               
         
                Section(header: Text("Product Category")) {
                                       Picker("Category", selection: $catVm.selectedCategory?.id) {
                                           ForEach(catVm.categories, id: \.id) { category in
                                               Text(category.name)
                                           }
                                       }
                                   }

               
               Section(header: Text("Product Image")) {
                   Text("Image 1")
               }
               
               Section(header: Text("Product Publish")) {
                   Button("Publish your new product!") {
                       
                   }
                   
               }
                           }
        }
    }
}`
```

it display this error `Trailing closure passed to parameter of type 'FormStyleConfiguration' that does not accept a closure` from this section  `Section(header: Text("Product Category")) { Picker("Category", selection: $catVm.selectedCategory?.id) { ForEach(catVm.categories, id: \.id) { category in Text(category.name) } } }`    
**Categry ViewModel:**
`final class CategoryViewModel : ObservableObject {

```
@Published var categories: [Category] = [Category]()
@Published var selectedCategory: Category? = nil

init() {
    Task {
        await getCategories()
    }
}

func getCategories() async {
    
    let result = await CategoryRepo.getAll()
    
    switch result {
    case .success(let data):
        categories = data
        selectedCategory = data.first
    
    case .failure: print("Cannot fetch categories...")
        
    }
}
```

}`
how can i solve it

Comment: Can you post the code for `CategoryViewModel`? I'm assuming there's something wrong where you initialize the `Picker` using `catVM` which makes the trailing closure fail the `@ViewBuilder` expectation of the `Form` initializer

Comment: I might not actually have needed the extra code - you're passing an optional as the `selection` parameter for `Picker`. If you unwrap `selectedCategory` first, does that work?

Comment: @mimo is right. Change the picker to `Picker("Category", selection: $catVm.selectedCategory)` and inside the picker do `Text(category.name).tag(category as Category?)`